# Como fazer um montador de Assembly simples

Tags: c, assembly, arm, x86

Estou aprendendo sobre arquitetura de processadores pretendo montar um assembler. Qual o procedimento e etapas para escrever um programa que faça a transformação do código escrito para o código de máquina?

O montador pode ser para ARM ou 8086 e pode ser em C.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow Anderson. Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender melhor o modelo da nossa comunidade. Qual é a sua dúvida sobre o assunto? Veja [como fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: É escrever a gramática do assembly? É escrever o parser? É emitir o código binário? É fazer o linking entre mais de um arquivo? É salvar o resultado em um formato executável? Qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: a duvida principal é escrever o parser

Answer (score 6):

O que você está pedindo é fazer um compilador simples, que recebe um código-fonte e produz um código de máquina.

#### Estrutura de um compilador

O processo de compilação normalmente é dividido nas seguintes etapas:

- Análise léxica.
- Análise sintática.
- Análise semântica.
- Geração de código intermediário.
- Geração de código objeto.
- Otimização de código.

E também frequentemente ocorrem mais algumas coisas em compiladores típicos:

- Alocação de registradores.
- Tratamento e recuperação de erros.
- Verificação e inferência de tipos.
- Gerenciamento de dependências e/ou linkagem de código.

Entretanto, como o seu projeto não é um grande produto comercial e o processo de compilação deverá ser apenas uma tradução 1-para-1 de instrução assembler para instrução de código de máquina, então a estrutura do seu compilador ficará bem mais enxuta.

---

#### Iniciando o seu compilador:

Primeiro, escolha um conjunto pequeno de instruções que o seu compilador irá aceitar. Comece pequeno e depois aumente. No seu código crie um `struct` ou coisa parecida para representar uma instrução. Basicamente esta estrutura terá um campo que equivale ao tipo da instrução e outros campos que representam os parâmetros/argumentos/operandos desta instrução. Você pode dar uma forçadinha e encaixar labels e diretivas neste `struct` também.

---

#### Análise léxica e sintática:

O ideal seria você criar um analisador léxico completo e um analisador sintático completo. Normalmente você usaria uma gramática léxica regular e uma gramática sintática livre-de-contexto. Mas, a menos que você tenha a mão alguma ferramenta pronta e domine este tipo de conhecimento, fazer isso seria um trabalhão muito oneroso. Então lhe proponho uma abordagem mais simples:

1. Divida o seu programa em uma sequência de linhas. Basicamente, leia o fonte inteiro e faça um split aonde encontrar um `\n`.
2. Divida cada linha em uma sequência de palavras. Basicamente, use os espaços para picar a linha em diversas "palavras".
3. Descarte as "palavras" que forem vazias (tamanho zero). Detecte aonde estão os comentários e descarte-os também. Descarte linhas que revelarem ser totalmente vazias.
4. As palavras que sobrarem na linha correspondem aos códigos da sua instrução.
5. Analise as palavras restantes para ver se você não terá que subdividir em palavras menores por causa de coisas como parênteses, colchetes, vírgulas, etc.
6. Identifique qual é o mnemônico da instrução e crie uma instância do seu `struct` para armazenar o que foi lido na linha.
7. Se nenhum mnemônico servir ou for reconhecido em uma determinada linha, emita um erro e pare. Como o seu projeto é simples, deixe o tratamento e recuperação de erros de lado (ao menos por enquanto), abortando o processo de compilação no primeiro erro encontrado.
8. Repita este processo para cada linha, criando ao final uma lista de instruções que representa o programa todo.

---

#### Análise semântica:

Tendo a lista das instruções do programa, cada uma dentro do seu devido `struct`, verifique se todos os labels e rotinas referenciados existem. Verifique se os argumentos, registradores e operandos usados em cada instrução são válidos, compatíveis entre si e com a instrução e se estão em uma quantidade certa/válida e na ordem certa/válida, tal como esperado pela instrução correspondente. Verifique tudo que achar pertinente. Se encontrar algo errado, emita um erro e pare.

Para fazer isso, provavelmente você vai precisar criar uma função no seu código em C especializada para analisar cada tipo distinto de instrução. Algo como `verificar_MOV()`, `verificar_POP()`, `verificar_ADD()`, etc.

---

#### Geração de código:

Primeiramente, você vai ter que calcular qual é o tamanho de cada instrução. Como você já fez a análise semântica, então, a menos que você tenha cometido algum erro, até aqui todas as instruções são válidas e bem-formadas. Com isso, você vai ter que descobrir quais são os valores de todos os *offsets* necessários para calcular todos os endereços necessários. Você deverá ter alguma tabela ou manual que explica como converter cada instrução em seu código de máquina correspondente, e você fará isso nesta etapa, guardando todos os códigos de máquinas resultantes em uma lista com uma relação 1-para-1 com as instruções que você guardou no `struct`. Se quiser, você pode guardar os códigos de máquina dentro do próprio `struct`.

Novamente, você provavelmente vai precisar de uma função de geração dde código especializada para cada tipo, tal como `gerar_codigo_MOV()`, `gerar_codigo_PUSH()`, `gerar_codigo_ADD()`, etc.

Finalizado isso, tudo que você tem que fazer é escrever os códigos de máquina sequencialmente dentro do arquivo executável. Talvez você tenha que acrescentar coisas como cabeçalhos nestes arquivos também.

---

#### Resultado:

Neste momento você deverá ter o seu compilador simples funcionando. Não há otimização de código. Não há geração de código intermediário (que é útil para gerar-se código para diferentes arquiteturas). O tratamento e recuperação de erros é mínimo. Como o seu programa é monolítico até agora, não há gerenciamento de dependências e/ou linkagem. Todas estas características podem ser adicionadas posteriormente de forma incremental uma de cada vez, caso você queira.

Além disso, você deverá estar usando um conjunto mínimo de instruções, e para a análise semântica e geração de código, provavelmente o seu compilador terá uma boa parte de código específico para cada instrução. Depois de ter um compilador mínimo implementado, se você tiver feito ele de forma modular, adicionar suporte a novos tipos de instrução, um-a-um não deverá ser muito difícil.

Por fim, como a sua linguagem é muito baixo nível, provavelmente não faz sentido falar-se em verificação e inferência de tipos e a alocação de registradores é algo que torna-se problema do usuário e não do compilador, então você provavelmente não precisará se preocupar com estes aspectos.